# Condtionally selecting values from a Numpy array returned from PyFITS

Tags: python, numpy, fits, pyfits

I have opened a FITS file in pyfits. The HEADER file reads `XTENSION='BINTABLE'` with `DIMENSION= 52989R x 36C` with 36 column tags like, `'ZBEST'`, `'ZQUALITY'`, `'M_B'`, `'UB'`, `'PGAL'` etc.

Now, I have to choose objects from the data with 'ZQUALITY' greater than 2 & 'PGAL' equals to 3. Then I have to make a histogram for the 'ZBEST' of the corresponding objects obeying the above conditions. Also I have to plot 'M_B' vs 'UB' for those objects.

At last I want to slice the 'ZBEST' into three slices (zbest < 0.5), (0.5 < zbest < 1.0), (zbest > 1.0) and want to plot histogram and 'M_B' vs 'UB' diagram of them separately.

I am stuck at choosing the data obeying the two conditions. Can anyone please tell me how can I choose the objects from the data satisfying both the conditions ('ZQUALITY' > 2 & 'PGAL' == 3 )? I am using like: `data.field[('zquality' > 2) & ('pgal'==3)]` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `data.field[('zquality' > 2) & ('pgal'==3)]` is asking for fields where the *string* `'zquality'` is greater than 2 (always true) and where the *string* `'pgal'` is equal to 3 (also always false).

Actually chances are you're getting an exception because `data.field` is a method on the Numpy recarray objects that PyFITS returns tables in.

You want something like `data[(data['zquality'] > 2) & (data['pgal'] == 3)]`.

This expression means "give me the rows of the 'zquality' column of `data` containing values greater than 2.  Then give me the rows of the 'pgal' column of `data` with values equal to three.  Now give me the full rows of `data` selected from the logical 'and' of the two row masks.